# Let $\left\vert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\vert\to 1,$ define $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R};\ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n.$ Is $f$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Suppose $(a_n)_n$ is a real sequence with $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\vert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\vert=1.\ $ Define $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R};\ f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n.$ By application of the [Limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) and comparing this sum to a geometric series (i.e. using the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) also), $f(x)$ converges for all $x\in (-1,1),\ $ and so we see that $f$ is well-defined. But can we prove that $f(x)$ is:

Continuous, differentiable etc?

I have tried to show that $f(x)$ is continuous i.e. showing that $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\left(f(a+h)-f(a)\right)=0$ via the following method:

$$f(a+h)-f(a) = (a_0 - a_0) + a_1(a+h-a) + a_2((a+h)^2-a^2) + a_3((a+h)^3-a^3) + \ldots$$

$$ = 0 + a_1 h + a_2 h (2a+h) + a_3 h (3a^2 + 3ah + h^2) + \ldots $$

$$ = h\left[ a_1 + a_2 (2a+h) + a_3 (3a^2 + 3ah + h^2) + \ldots \right]. $$

Using also the fact that $\vert a \vert < 1,$ can it be proven that the sum inside the square bracket is **bounded** as $h\to 0\ ?$ It would then follow that $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\left(f(a+h)-f(a)\right)=0.$

Or is there some other method to prove continuity of $f$?

Comment: The sum of a power series is always $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ in its disk of convergence.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe is this a result covered in Rudin? Is it real analysis or complex analysis? Where can I read about this result?

Comment: Yes, it is certainly covered in Rudin, at least in complex analysis. But the proof is not so difficult : try to prove that the series converges *uniformly* in every interval $[-a,a]$ with $0 \leq a<1$, and see why it implies the continuity of the function.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson yes this is well-known. You can find it in any book of real analysis.

Answer (score 1):

With $|a|<1$ and demanding that $|h|<\bar h$, the difference series has a bound
$$
|f(a+h)-f(a)|\le \frac{|h|}{\bar h}\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|((|a|+\bar h)^k-|a|^k)
$$
So select $0<\bar h=1-|a|-\delta$, then the bound is again smaller than
$$
\le\frac{|h|}{\bar h}\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|(1-\delta)^k
$$
and that series has a finite limit by the quotient test.

Comment: Sorry but what is the quotient test?

Comment: The quotient test for series convergence. For the bound it gives a limit $1−δ<1$ together with the given limit of the coefficient quotients.

Comment: Please state what the quotient test for convergence is. I have not heard of this term before.

Comment: Ok, the common name in English uses the other term for quotient, it is [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)

Comment: ah I thought it might be.Just wanted to make sure.